# Script stopping during execution

Tags: python

I'm doing a check for data migration failures in my database, and while my Python script works fine for a smaller amount of data, it currently is stopping in the middle of execution. The cmd is still in execution state but doesn't appear to be running at some point, and I need to manually abort it using Ctrl+C.

Code and comments below:

```
import collections
import csv

a=[]

with open('FailedIds.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        a.append(line) #builds array of unique row IDs that failed in migration. Contains 680k rows.

with open("OldDbAll.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = list(csv.reader(f))
    dict = {i[0]:[(x) for x in i[1:]] for i in zip(*l)} #builds dictionary containing all rows and columns from our old DB, key = column header, values = arrays of values. Contains 3 million rows and 9 columns, 200MB in file size.

string=''
print("Done building dictionary")

with open('Fix.txt', 'w') as f:
  print(",".join(dict.keys()),file=f)
  for i in range(len(dict['UNIQUEID'])):
    for j in range(len(a)):
      if a[j].strip()==dict['UNIQUEID'][i]: #matching failure row ID to the dictionary unique ID array
        for key in dict:
          string+=dict[key][i]+"," #prints the data to be re-migrated
        print(string,file=f)
        string=''
```

When I first ran this script overnight, I got around 50k rows after manually aborting the python script. I thought that was OK because my computer might have hibernated. However, this morning I got 1k rows after running the script throughout yesterday and into the night. I plan to restart my computer and set it to not sleep the next time, but I would like to get all 600k+ rows as the output, and currently I'm nowhere near that amount.

I searched around and Python's array size limit should be well above what I'm using it for, so something else is causing the program to hang. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you add some logging to your script that indicates where what it's doing, so you can get an idea of where the problem is.

Comment: How big is `dict`?  Repeated string concatenation is _very_ slow.

Comment: @martineau yeah I was going do that in the next iteration. Forgot to mention that. And John, it's in the comments, but 3 million rows x 9 columns

Comment: 3 million?!  Holy cow.  Repeated concatenation of large strings is _very very_ slow.

Comment: @Yaga So `for i in range(len(dict['UNIQUEID']))` loops over *3 million* items, and `for j in range(len(a))` loops over *680 thousand* items, meaning `a[j].strip()==dict['UNIQUEID'][i]` has to be executed over ***2 trillion*** times?!

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah it's a huge file.. :( I'm working on reducing the file size of OldDbAll.txt, but it's still going to be massive. We're moving databases so this is not a normal occurrence

Comment: @Yaga The size of the files isn't that important. It's the extreme inefficiency of your algorithm that is causing all the problems. You can improve things quite easily by using a `set` of pre-stripped lines for `a`. Then you can replace the second loop and if-statement with `if dict['UNIQUEID'][i] in a:`. And as suggested by John Gordon, you should also write the individual strings directly to the output file rather than concatenating them all first. Creating trillions of temporary strings is **very** expensive and totally unnecessary.

Comment: That's a really good point. I'll make that code change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this loop is the reason your code takes so long to run:

```
for key in dict:
  string+=dict[key][i]+"," #prints the data to be re-migrated
print(string,file=f)
string=''
```

String concatenation is *slow*, and this loop does a *lot* of it.

I don't think you need to concatenate at all -- just write to the file as you go:

```
for key in dict:
  f.write(dict[key][i]+",")
```

Comment: Maybe write the `","` separately as well. The fewer temporary strings (and memory allocations), the better.

Comment: Made the changes you guys suggested and it's working a lot faster. Thanks!